# MAX(Date_Column) nested query makes BigQuery estimate wrong data processing

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp, data-processing, subquery

I have a job that aggregates data from our transaction table into a reporting table in BigQuery. The reporting table has a DATE column and the transaction table has TIMESTAMP and our server is in UTC timezone.

The below query works. However, BigQuery shows a data processing estimate of 577GB against an actual of 1.27GB. This difference happens because of the nested WHERE condition, where I am using MAX(est_date) to determine which timestamps to process in the transaction table.

When using the query, it shows 577GB, but when I manually type in the same date value, it shows 1.27GB. I'd ignore it as a bad estimate, but today, my jobs actually failed showing the quota was exceeded. The MAX(date_column) part of the query in itself only processes 1kb.

```
SELECT
  DATE(timestamp_column, "America/New_York") AS est_date,
  AVG(number_column) AS metric
FROM prod.`my_table`
WHERE timestamp_column >= (
                      SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(COALESCE(MAX(est_date), '2022-06-01'), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 'America/New_York')
                      FROM dashboards.`report_table`
                    )
  AND timestamp_column < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE('America/New_York'), 'America/New_York')
GROUP BY est_date
```

I also tried changing things up  a bit by using a CTE and a nested table, using CROSS JOINs and using `(SELECT MAX(timestamp_column) FROM CTE)`, but they all estimate 577GB.

Could the mismatch between my transaction table having a TIMESTAMP column and my reporting table having a DATE column be the culprit?

**EDIT:**

I DECLARED a variable to store the nested query part and passed it to the main query. That made it process ~1.3GB, even though it estimated 577GB. I will still keep the question open, if someone can explain the root cause behind this and suggest an ideal solution.

**EDIT 2:**

The splitting of jobs now caused another error in Airflow:
`self._exceptiongoogle.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts`

I guess I need to still resolve my problem.

Comment: Could you please share the error code that bigquery is returning to you?

Comment: It's been a while and I don't have the exact error message anymore.

Using DECLARE fixed the issue, but I couldn't simply put a SELECT statement and use write_disposition and destination table parameters to have BQ do the inserts for me, so I just changed the query to an INSERT SELECT.